# storing Dictionary as value on another Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a dictionary that takes a key and returns another dictionary that takes a different key and returns a value, but I'm having difficulty on implementing this.

I've tried something like this:

```
FirstDict[key1]=SecondDict
SecondDict[key2]=Final Value
```

I'd like to be able to call it like `SecondDict[key1][key2]` but I'm unable to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You can create multi-level nested dictionaries with `collections.defaultdict`, like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
def multi_level_dict():
    return defaultdict(multi_level_dict)
```

You can use it like this

```
my_dict = multi_level_dict()
my_dict[1][2][3] = "cabbage"
my_dict[1][4][5] = "salad"
from pprint import pprint
pprint(my_dict)
# {1: {2: {3: 'cabbage'},
#      4: {5: 'salad'}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a =  {}
>>> b = {}
>>> a['key1'] = b
>>> b['key2'] = 'final value'
>>> a['key1']
{'key2': 'final value'}
>>> a['key1']['key2']
'final value'
>>>
```

I tested, it works!

Comment: a['1'] = {'2':{'3':3}}  then call a['1']['2']['3']

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested dictionaries with `NestedDict`

```
>>> from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict
>>> nd = NestedDict()
>>> nd["a", "a"] = 0
>>> nd["a", "b"] = 1
>>> nd["b"] = 2
>>> nd
NestedDict({'a': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 'b': 2})
```

Once you have a NestedDict, get value using tuples as in a flat dictionary

```
>>> nd["a", "a"]
0
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`